# Powerpoint Macro "MarginRight" Code is not working

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am writing powerpoint macros code for formatting a table.

I'm not sure why the text won't adjust based on the Right Margin value. It is still very close to the border (similar to having it at 0).

```
    'Add Margins of Row 2 onwards, Column 3
    For lRow = 2 To oTbl.Rows.Count
        With oTbl.Cell(lRow, 3).Shape.TextFrame
            .HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorNone
            .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
            .MarginRight = 72
            .MarginLeft = 120
        End With
    Next
```

There's no error prompt.

Did I miss anything here?

Comment: 120 is a large value for MarginRight. How wide is the cell overall? With 72 pts from the left and 120 pts from the right, is there still room for content?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what a minimal reproducible example looks like, so other readers don't have to reconstruct a macro around your code snippet to test it. This is the kind of sample to post in the future:

```
Sub SetTableMargin()
    Dim oTbl As Table
    Dim lRow As Integer
    Set oTbl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Table
    For lRow = 2 To oTbl.Rows.Count
        With oTbl.Cell(lRow, 3).Shape.TextFrame
            .HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorNone
            .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
            .MarginRight = 0
            .MarginLeft = 0
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

This sample sets both the right and left margins to 0. As @tellyn mentioned, your measurements are quite large. 72 is 1" and and 120 is 1.67", so that would have to be a really big table cell.

Comment: Edited the code to show .MarginRight = 1 and .MarginLeft = 1, it did work! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate an upvote if you found it useful.